# How to write Hebrew characters?

Tags: database, language, encoding

Our database is set to:

```
define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8’);
define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
```

As a result, entered Hebrew characters in a post are turned into question marks (?) on saving of the post. What is the required procedure to have the database support Hebrew characters in Wordpress posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your mysql database charset and website charset.
They should be same - utf8.

Comment: Dear @moonvader. Could you please briefly outline the steps necessary to check both charsets? Thank you!

Comment: If you are using phpMyAdmin you can follow this steps - https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403914/default-mysql-character-set-and-collation