# Hebrew Characters Have gone bad

Tags: language, characters, collation

I have read [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208387/how-to-write-hebrew-characters):

I have tried the following:

```
ALTER database mydbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER table ext_hebrewText CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

My table has one column in Hebrew: 
[image]

And I have various Javascripts that format and color it to show on the screen. 
This is the way it is current showing: 
[image]
With some other changes, I see all question marks.

My current config.php settings are:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci;');
```

What's the right combination to get them to display.  Everything used to work fine.  I think it broke on one of the recent WordPress auto upgrades. 
It's not a font issue, because I see those same characters when I inspect the HTML on Chrome debugger tool.

Comment: Nearly impossible to guess without hands on access to the data. Since it's not even native WP table I _highly_ doubt WP upgrade affected it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally shocked.  After hours of trying things and testing, I finally found the "Settings" then "Readings" option below: "Encoding for pages and feeds".  After changing from UTF-7 to UTF-8, everything looks good again.

[image]

And even stranger, after changing it to UTF-8, the option disappears from the page. According to [WordPress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen), this option was removed since release 3.5.